# Verifying a Trello webhook

Tags: php, node.js

I'm having trouble verifying a Trello webhook in both PHP or Node.js.  I copied the Node.js version directly from here: https://developers.trello.com/page/webhooks

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function verifyTrelloWebhookRequest(request, secret, callbackURL) {
  var base64Digest = function (s) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(s).digest('base64');
  }
  var content = JSON.stringify(request.body) + callbackURL;
  var doubleHash = base64Digest(base64Digest(content));
  var headerHash = base64Digest(request.headers['x-trello-webhook']);
  return doubleHash == headerHash;
}
```

With the Node.js version I did substitute values for request, secret, and callbackURL however.  The PHP version I've got is:

```
function h( $s ) {
    return base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $s, $secret ) );
}

$incomingHash = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_TRELLO_WEBHOOK'];
$h2 = h( h( $post . $callbackURL ) );
$h1 = h( $incomingHash );
```

At this point I'm thinking I've got the "secret" wrong although I've tried the token, oauth secret, and the api key or Trello changed the hashing algorithm but I don't want to rule out my specialty (hairbrained mistakes).  FWIW I did verify the callback URL is EXACTLY what Trello's API says it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working by returning the binary of the HMAC hash and by using the OAuth1 secret.

```
function h( $s ) {
    return base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $s, $secret, true ) );
}

$incomingHash = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_TRELLO_WEBHOOK'];
$h2 = h( h( $post . $callbackURL ) );
$h1 = h( $incomingHash );
```

You can lookup the callback URL used via: https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#tokenstokenwebhooks

Comment: seems your code missing all variables or I am not sure you put whole code here.

Comment: @AshishDwivedi Sorry I figured it would be clearer.  `$secret` is the oAuth1 secret that you get when you go here: https://trello.com/app-key  The `$callbackURL` is the URL Trello calls that you setup when you created the webhook.  `$post` is the incoming post request for example: `$post = file_get_contents( "php://input" );`. So if `$h1 == $h2` then the webhook is valid.  Does that help?